# groupadd: invalid group ID '' error with docker

Tags: docker

I am following [Minimal ADE](https://gitlab.com/ApexAI/minimal-ade) to start my [ADE](https://ade-cli.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) journey. The [README.md](https://gitlab.com/ApexAI/minimal-ade/-/blob/master/README.md?ref_type=heads) provides all the instructions to set up ADE and it works perfectly with `ade start`. However my question is that the same readme above says that a docker image is built using the command `docker build -t image .` Hence I am expecting to run the `image` using `docker run -it image` but this results in `groupadd: invalid group ID ''`. I think the issue seems to be something with the [entrypoint](https://gitlab.com/ApexAI/minimal-ade/-/blob/master/entrypoint?ref_type=heads#L25-32) or the [env.sh](https://gitlab.com/ApexAI/minimal-ade/-/blob/master/env.sh?ref_type=heads).
I am still learning docker and any help would be really appreciated